# The standard topology on the set of residues modulo n

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, ring-theory, algebraic-topology, finite-groups

I want to define a topology on the set of residue modulo $p$, $\mathbb{Z}_p$.
what is the standard topology on that set?

Comment: Since $\mathbb{Z}_{p}$ is discrete, then I assume the discrete topology would be the standard topology.

Answer (score 4):

It's a finite set; I'd say that a typical topology is the discrete topology. That's certainly the one that comes up in the fibration $z \mapsto z^p$ over the unit circle.

Answer (score 1):

Usually we have for each group $\Bbb{Z}/n\Bbb{Z}$, with $n\in \Bbb{N}$, the discrete topology (for 
the $p$-adic integers $\Bbb{Z}_p$, it is the $p$-adic topology, where $p$ is prime).